# React native fetch request to .net core 3 api network request fail

Tags: api, react-native, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are experiencing an issue where we use 3 different req methods (fetch, axios, frisbee)
from an react native app running on an android emulator.

server logs suggests that server receives the requests, validates it and responds 200ok

but react native shows type error network error sometimes create error

any suggestions?

code:

```
handleLoginUser() {

    axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://example.com/users/login',
            data: {
                email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
                password: '1234567890'
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            response.json();
        })

        .catch(function(response) {
           console.error(response);
        });

    fetch('https://example.com/users/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: 'ec223e@gmail.com',
                password: '1234567890'
            })
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            response.json();
        })
        .then(result => {
            if (result.success) {
                alert("Login successful");
            } else
                alert("Unable to Login");
        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.error(response);
        });
    const Frisbee = require('frisbee');


    const api = new Frisbee({
        baseURI: 'https://example.com', // optional
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            email: 'aaasdkgur@gmail.com',
            password: '1234567890'
        }
    });
    api.post('/users/login')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            response.json();
        })
        .then(result => {
            if (result.success) {
                alert("Login successful");
            } else
                alert("Unable to Login");
        }).catch(function(response) {
             console.error(response);
        });
}
```

debug stack

axios

```
"TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27200:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:32754:27)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31838:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31665:16)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31775:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:6075:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5503:44)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5216:17
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5457:13)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5215:14)"
```

fetch

```
"TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27200:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:32754:27)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31838:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31665:16)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31775:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:6075:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5503:44)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5216:17
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5457:13)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5215:14)"
```

frisbee

```
"Error: Network Error
    at createError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:122025:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:121933:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:32754:27)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31838:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31665:16)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31775:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:6075:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5503:44)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5216:17
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5457:13)"
```

Server logs

```
2019-12-12 16:44:32.457 +03:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://example.com/users/login application/json 55
2019-12-12 16:44:32.457 +03:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://example.com/users/login application/json; charset=utf-8 52
2019-12-12 16:44:32.460 +03:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api)'
2019-12-12 16:44:32.460 +03:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api)'
2019-12-12 16:44:32.461 +03:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "LoginUser", controller = "Users"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserResultModel] LoginUser(c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserModel) on controller c.Api.Controllers.UsersController (c.Api).
2019-12-12 16:44:32.461 +03:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "LoginUser", controller = "Users"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserResultModel] LoginUser(c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserModel) on controller c.Api.Controllers.UsersController (c.Api).
2019-12-12 16:44:32.462 +03:00 [INF] LoginUser() started for - aaasdkgur@gmail.com
2019-12-12 16:44:32.462 +03:00 [INF] LoginUser() started for - ec223e@gmail.com
2019-12-12 16:44:32.473 +03:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://example.com/users/login application/json; charset=utf-8 52
2019-12-12 16:44:32.474 +03:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api)'
2019-12-12 16:44:32.475 +03:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "LoginUser", controller = "Users"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserResultModel] LoginUser(c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserModel) on controller c.Api.Controllers.UsersController (c.Api).
2019-12-12 16:44:32.475 +03:00 [INF] LoginUser() started for - xyz@gmail.com
2019-12-12 16:44:32.758 +03:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserResultModel'.
2019-12-12 16:44:32.758 +03:00 [INF] Executed action c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api) in 297.38800000000003ms
2019-12-12 16:44:32.759 +03:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api)'
2019-12-12 16:44:32.759 +03:00 [INF] Request finished in 302.1514ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
2019-12-12 16:44:32.812 +03:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserResultModel'.
2019-12-12 16:44:32.812 +03:00 [INF] Executed action c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api) in 337.31350000000003ms
2019-12-12 16:44:32.812 +03:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api)'
2019-12-12 16:44:32.812 +03:00 [INF] Request finished in 339.45410000000004ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
2019-12-12 16:44:32.966 +03:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'c.Api.Models.Users.LoginUserResultModel'.
2019-12-12 16:44:32.966 +03:00 [INF] Executed action c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api) in 504.8709ms
2019-12-12 16:44:32.966 +03:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'c.Api.Controllers.UsersController.LoginUser (c.Api)'
2019-12-12 16:44:32.966 +03:00 [INF] Request finished in 508.91540000000003ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

[image: Postman Request]

Comment: can you request the endpoint with Postman/Insomnia (just to see the raw response from your api...it might help)

Comment: I added postman response image.

Comment: OK - the payload is coming back. API is good. Can you debug w/ Chome to step through your app-side code? Also Charles Proxy is a very decent tool. You can use it to see the outgoing payload (in case there is something wrong there)

Comment: one more thing - are you using ios and are you making a https request or http (from your app). i don't think http will work without a setting change.